# Sign up form data is not storing on firebase except the image

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to create sign up form in **react-native** using **Firebase**.I've used `Fetch Blob` and `Document Picker` libraries for getting image and **upload** it to firebase. And I'm also trying to save the user's **name, email, and password** in **realtime database**. But unfortunately, the user data is not going to save in database except the **image is uploaded** in the **firebase storage**.

**Here is my Firebase Auth Code**

```
 handleSignupOnPress = () => {
    const {image, email, password} = this.state;
    let validation = this.validateData();
    console.warn(validation);
    if (validation == true) {
      this.toggleLoading();
      firebaseService
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
          // console.warn("User SignUp Successfully");
          this.uploadImage(image);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.toggleLoading();
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          alert(errorMessage);
          // console.warn("ERROR => ", errorCode, errorMessage);
        });
    }
  };
```

**Here is image Upload Code**

```
 // First Uploading image and download Image URI then call saveUserToDB()...
  uploadImage(uri, mime = 'image/jpeg') {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const uploadUri =
        Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;
      let uploadBlob = '';

      const imageRef = firebaseService
        .storage()
        .ref('images')
        .child(uuid.v4());

      fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
        .then(data => {
          return Blob.build(data, {type: `${mime};BASE64`});
        })
        .then(blob => {
          uploadBlob = blob;
          return imageRef.put(blob, {contentType: mime});
        })
        .then(() => {
          uploadBlob.close();

          const downnloadImageURI = imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            this.setState(
              {
                imageURI: url,
              },
              () => {
                alert('ImageURI ==> ', this.state.imageURI);
                this.saveUserInfo();
              },
            );
          });
          return downnloadImageURI;
        })
        .then(url => {
          resolve(url);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.toggleLoading();
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }
```

**Here is code for saving user's data**

```
saveUserInfo = () => {
    const {userName, email, password, imageURI} = this.state;
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    const uid = firebaseService.auth().currentUser.uid;
    const params = {
      image: imageURI,
      username: userName,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    //firebaseService.database().ref('/Users').push(params)
    firebaseService
      .database()
      .ref('/Users')
      .child(uid)
      .set(params)
      .then(res => {
        this.toggleLoading();
        navigate('Login');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err);
      });
  };
```

**Here are screenshots of Firebase Console**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue. The issue was in this piece of code.

```
 const downnloadImageURI = imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            this.setState(
              {
                imageURI: url,
              },
              () => {
                alert('ImageURI ==> ', this.state.imageURI);
                this.saveUserInfo();
              },
            );
```

**setState** was not working and **calback** was not fired.
And I've made it like this way

```
  const downnloadImageURI = imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
               this.saveUserInfo(url)
                );}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the "Rules" in database given permission to "Write"

1. Go to the firebase console and open your project.
2. Go to the database and search for "Rules" tab.
3. Check the rules are set as below

{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: both read and write rules are true.If I comment all the image upload code and just want to save user email password name etc then it saved otherwise not only image

Comment: It should work. If still it doesn't work then there are high chances of some error, try finding that.